# Does calling printf without a proper prototype invoke undefined behavior?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, function-prototypes

Does this innocent looking program invoke undefined behavior:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes invoking `printf()` without a proper prototype (from the standard header `<stdio.h>` or from a properly written declaration) invokes undefined behavior.

As documented in the C Standard:

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>
> - If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the default argument promotions. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.

In more pragmatic words, in the absence of a prototype for `printf`, the compiler generates the calling sequence as if `printf` was defined as `int printf(const char *, int)` which may be quite different and incompatible with the actual implementation of `printf` in the standard library, defined as `int printf(const char restrict *format, ...)`.

Ancient ABIs were regular enough that this would not cause a problem, but modern (eg 64-bit) ABIs use more efficient calling sequences that make the above code definitely incorrect.

As a consequence, this famous classic C program could fail too, without the `#include <stdio.h>` or at least a proper prototype for `printf`:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");  // undefined behavior
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor quibble: invoking `printf()` without a proper prototype invokes undefined behaviour. Whether it comes from `<stdio.h>` does not matter. A program may alternatively provide its own prototyped declaration of `printf`.

Comment: @hvd: agreed, I shall reword the answer. The prototype can come from a different source, but it must be compatible with the actual definition of `printf` in the C library.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking the answer to your question (see title) is *no*. As you yourself point it out, the header file [instead of using `<stdio.h>` can be replaced by a *properly written declaration*.

Comment: @Matsmath: good thinking: the question is the title commands a detailed answer.  At best the answer would be *not necessarily*. The question and the code sample in the body of the question unambiguously deserve a *yes* answer.

Comment: This is a rhetorical question, @chqrlie, very educative for inexperienced programmers to read. From pragmatical point of view, a common mistake is to sometimes forget include a header, but _not turning compiler warnings on_ is simply bad practice. Some modern compilers even explicitly warn in case `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` etc. omitted, but a C library function call of same name and usage is being called. FYI, I've tried hard to induce UB by making arguments to your innocent code increasingly complicated. No UB detected so far. Hope my UNIX host won't die for undefined reasons one fine day (-:

Comment: @chqrlie: "The prototype can come from a different source, but it must be compatible with the actual definition of `printf` in the C library." -- Actually, no. A program is at liberty to provide an implementation of a function called `printf` that is *different* (in functionality and / or prototype) from what the standard library defines, *as long as* it does not *also* include `<stdio.h>` (at which point you would have conflicting declarations). This is also the reason why standard headers are not allowed to include each other.

Comment: @DevSolar: I believe behavior would be undefined if a function or variable were called `printf` *unless* the identifier had static or (for a variable) block scope.  I believe behavior would be undefined if a compilation unit included `<stdio.h>` and then subsequently used `printf` as any kind of name with block scope; I'm not sure about cases where `printf` is defined as a name within a scope block that is closed prior to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @supercat: 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers, "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses [...] are always reserved *for use as identifiers with external linkage." So yes, you are correct, static only. But you can still have a `static int printf( int );` -- as long as you don't `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @DevSolar: Allowing static functions with the name of identifiers that aren't used elsewhere is helpful, though I think it might have been better to have established a convention, once the preprocessor was invoked by default, that any standard library functions which were added after that would be given implementation-reserved names, their standard-defined names would be macros that map to the implementation-defined ones, and code should indicate via some means what version of the Standard it is expecting.  That would make it possible to add new identifiers to the default library without...

Comment: ...breaking existing code, even if the code happens to use global identifiers whose name matches the "C-code" name of the new functions [e.g. a "gprintf" function which accepts a function pointer and a void* might be mapped via macro in stdiox.h to external identifier "__stdiox_gprintf" or "__f295" [depending upon the name-length limits of the linker], neither of which would conflict with a user function "gprintf".

Comment: @DevSolar: Would there be anything illegitimate about a compiler which, on each compilation picked a new magic number, and made `<stdio.h>` include a declaration `int printf(char const *fmt, __MAGIC_1324E491_);`, and had `printf` behave arbitrarily if it didn't include the proper magic number?  I think the prototype has to come from `<stdio.h>` to guarantee defined behavior.

Comment: @supercat:  I do think the prototype must come from `<stdio.h>`, but I cannot find language in the Standard to support this claim.  The standard header could for example add attributes to tell the compiler how to invoke this library function.

Comment: @chqrlie: I wish the authors of the Standard would recognize that what would be most helpful would be a focus on how implementations should behave *when practical*, or how they should indicate that behaviors would be (in the implementer's judgment) "impractical".  That would eliminate the need to omit behaviors that are practical on "only" 99% of implementations.  If implementations that don't support common constructs were required to indicate that via macro or other means, the choice of support or non-support would remain a quality-of-implementation issue, but...

Comment: ...properly-written programs would be able to reject compilers that don't support necessary features, rather than venturing into UB-land.

Comment: @chqrlie How can the implicit declaration of `printf`, in your example, know that the first argument should be assumed to be a `const char*` and not just an `int`?
Does it (at the compile time) have enough knowledge to identify which is the address to a string constant and which is just an integer?

Comment: While Appendix J is informative, it is a consolidation of the *Undefined Behaviours* listed throughout the document; so para 6.5.2.2 normatively defines (?!) the *Undefined Behaviour*

Comment: @morimn: The compiler would have no difficulty inferring a prototype `int printf(char *);` from the call `printf("Hello world\n")`, and ABIs in the 70s and 80s were simple and allowed all scalar arguments to be passed uniformly as 1 or 2 machine words on the stack or via registers.  Modern system use more complex ABIs to improve performance, potentially passing arguments in incompatible ways to functions defined as `int p1(char *)` and `int p2(char *, ...)`.

Comment: @Andrew: good point. Answer amended!

Answer (score 0):

C was originally implemented on platforms where passing a variable number of arguments to a function call wouldn't pose any difficulty, and where a function call like `foo("Hey", "there", 123);` would be processed the same way if the function signature were any of the following:

- `int foo(char const *p, char const *q, int x);`
- `int foo(char const *p, char const *q, ...);`
- `int foo(char const *p, ...);`

On some platforms, however, the number and format of passed arguments must be known in advance; C implementations for such platforms may accommodate this by treating `...` as a `void*`, and having calling code construct and pass the argument of a structure containing the passed arguments.  On such platforms, the function call may need to pass `p`, `q`, and `x` as three arguments, pass `p`, `q`, and the address of `x` as three arguments, or build a structure holding `q` and `x`, and pass `p` along with the address of that structure as two arguments.

If a compiler doesn't know where `...` belongs in an argument list, it would have no way of knowing how to format the arguments.