# segfault when printing memory

Tags: c, memory, disassembly

I wrote some code to read data from address. This address belongs to code segment ( I disassemble my binary and lookup where main is located, so address is from there). The main goal is to change the content. When i printf it , it cause a segfault. Is it some kind of protection ?

```
void at(){


    char *p = 0x0000000100000f47;
    printf("%c", p[0]);

}

int main(){

    at();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are running your code on an operating system, and that operating system does not give your program access to physical memory, nor has it happened to assign the virtual address 0x0000000100000f47 to your program/process.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38686502/4068338

Comment: Why not `char *p = (char *)main;`. That way you don't have to worry about absolute addresses and relocations.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it some kind of protection ?

Yes. Segmentation! That's why you get a segmentation fault.

> I disassemble my binary and lookup where main is located, so address is from there

that doesn't say much; as an executable is loaded, parts of it get *relocated*, so they end up at different positions.

That's a fairly complex process (and error-prone), and it involves libc/rtloader/your OS/black magic; there might even be memory layout randomization going on here (probably not, though, for your code), so that the runtime intentionally makes sure you can't "guess" memory locations of certain things.

Comment: ok, i get it. it was a dummy question indeed. probably it is imposible for a computer to  locate my binary in same memory space always. thanks

Comment: it is possible, but it's not what executable loaders do